how to handle multiple queries in @Validate
currently I have GET end point where I receiving some query params.
initially I was getting one query param, but now I need to receive two query params.
my current code when I needed on query param was:
@Get("path/*")
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Validate({
    request: [
      { name: 'param1', type: 'param', schema: Type.String() },
      { name: '*', type: 'param', schema: Type.String() },
      { name: 'query1', type: 'query', schema: Type.Union([Type.Literal('true'), Type.Literal('false')]) },
    ],
    response: GetReply,
  })
  async nameFunction(
      @Param("param1") param1: string,
      @Param("*") param2: string,
      @Query() query1: string,
      @Res() res: FastifyReply,
      @Headers("Authorization") authorization?: string, 
    ) : Promise<GetReplyType | never>{

    logic...
    };


and I tried to add another query param but I'm getting error, this was the code that I tried:
@Get("path/*")
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Validate({
    request: [
      { name: 'param1', type: 'param', schema: Type.String() },
      { name: '*', type: 'param', schema: Type.String() },
      { name: 'query1', type: 'query', schema: Type.Union([Type.Literal('true'), Type.Literal('false')]) },
      { name: 'query2', type: 'query', schema: Type.Optional(Type.String()) },
    ],
    response: GetReply,
  })
  async nameFunction(
      @Param("param1") param1: string,
      @Param("param2") param2: string,
      @Query() query1: string,
      @Res() res: FastifyReply,
      @Headers("Authorization") authorization?: string, 
      @Query() query2?: string,
    ) : Promise<GetReplyType | never>{

    logic...
    };


any idea what I'm doing wrong?

If you use @Query() without a param that refers to the name of the query expected the decorator gonna return an object with the query params, maybe the first code works but for inference of NestJS and then broke because you are trying to use multiple @Query decorators without the name of the queryParam inside like @Query('queryParamName').
You have 2 valid approachs to take, the first one is to call one @Query() and then destructuring the Query Object returned. The other one is to add @Query('queryName') queryDefinitionName for each query param that you want to handle in the request.
